# Purchasing an HMO for use as a family home

Tags: united-kingdom, homeownership

I am based in the UK and wish to purchase a house that is currently set up as an HMO (although I don't know what use class it's currently registered as - It was previously used as sheltered accommodation for the elderly.) There is now no-one living there.

Are there any legal processes or fees that I should be aware of, in order to purchase this home and use it as my family home; outside of the usual conveyancing costs? Do I need to apply for planning permission for change of use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C3a class is a standard family/single occupancy dwelling. C4 class
> refers to small HMOs (of between 3 and 6 occupiers) and Sui Generis
> literally means “in a class of its own” and covers large HMOs of 7 or
> more people.
>
> You **always** need planning permission to move in and out of the Sui
> Generis use class, so any HMO of 7 or more people needs planning
> permission regardless of location.
>
> It is a **Permitted Development Right** to move between C3 and C4
> classes and back again, so in most cases, a small HMO does not need
> planning permission. However, you may also need planning permission if
> your HMO is in the C4 class and your local authority has an Article 4
> Direction.

https://www.portico.com/blog/landlord-advice/do-i-need-planning-permission-for-my-hmo

Classes of buildings and permission required to move between:

https://www.planningportal.co.uk/info/200130/common_projects/9/change_of_use/2

The above is for England, the rules are different for other parts of the UK.

Comment: Thanks. How can I find out what the current class is on the house?

Comment: Your solicitor should be asking the vendor for details of any planning permissions obtained, and you/they can check with the local planning office. Many areas have planning documents online.